# How to Apply Media Query in IE8 Conditional Statements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

i am trying to apply a media query if the browser is IE8 , is there any format to write and work it out?

Comment: IE8 doesn't understand media queries in the first place, so there's that...

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is IE8 with:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
```

And inside the ie8.css you will work with the media query. To make this HTML5/CSS3 feauture also work in IE8 you have to use a library, like

```
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is what I'd do also. Be sure to add it after your main stylesheet so the IE 8 specific styles override your main styles.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesnt support Media Queries, but JavaScript libraries like [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) can be used to make it work.

Comment: <!--[if lte IE 8]>
       <style>@media screen and (max-width:1024px) screen\9{
          padding-bottom:10% !important; 
         }
        
        </style>
<![endif]--> i have tried with the above code, can any one suggest in whicj format i will work out?